# Put json value to Hazelcast as json format from nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, hazelcast

How can I put json flow file to Hazelcast cache?
when I put data it has a binary format.
Flow file content example:

```json
{
  "InsCode": 72055516303318490,
  "IsinCode": "IRO9MKBT6041",
  "Symbol": "ضمخا8009",
  "Company": "اختيارخ اخابر-12000-1401/08/29",
  "LastTradeTime": 61457,
  "FirstPrice": 0,
  "ClosePrice": 1,
  "LastPrice": 1,
  "TransactionCount": 0,
  "Volume": 0,
  "Value": 0,
  "LowPrice": 0,
  "HighPrice": 0,
  "YesyterdayPrice": 1,
  "EPS": null,
  "BaseVolume": 1,
  "UnkownCol1": 200,
  "Flow": 3,
  "SectorID": 64,
  "MaxAllowedPrice": 100000,
  "MinAlloedPrice": 1,
  "NumberOfShare": 1000,
  "YVal": 311,
  "DateKey": "20220516",
  "CreatedAt": "2022-05-16 09:54:01.887Z"
}
```

But when I get data from Hazelcast API it would be like this:

[image]

In response header, content-type is application/binary
[image]

Comment: Please provide more information how you are calling Hazelcast, what APIs are you using?